# How to Change AnyLogic Experiment Running Speed Programmatically?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to control the running speed of my model programmatically, because in my simulation, if it is not working hour, nothing happens. I wrote the code below and used a cyclical event that cycle every hour to execute it. I am not sure why it does not work. Thanks for the help!

```
    Date date = date();
if (getDayOfWeek(date)==1||getDayOfWeek(date)==7)
    {
    getEngine().runFast();
    }
else if (getHourOfDay(date)<8||getHourOfDay(date)==12||getHourOfDay(date)>=17)
    {
    getEngine().runFast();
    }
else
    {
    getEngine().setRealTimeScale(5);
    }
```

Comment: What do you observe? Which part of the code is triggered? Share some more observations. You may need to play with `setRealTimeMode(false)` if it always runs fast.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getEngine().runFast();` which in the documentation says

> The run is done in virtual time mode regardless any settings.

But I could not get it to work without adding the `getEngine().setRealTimeMode(false);` code

I tested this and it works - the engine time jumps from weekday 6 (Friday) to weekday 2 (Monday)

```
if (getDayOfWeek()==1||getDayOfWeek()==7) {
   getEngine().setRealTimeMode(false);
    getEngine().runFast();
} else if (getHourOfDay()<8||getHourOfDay()==12||getHourOfDay()>=17){
   getEngine().setRealTimeMode(false);
    getEngine().runFast();
} else {
    getEngine().setRealTimeMode(true);
    getEngine().setRealTimeScale(5);
}
```

Note that you don't need to get date as the default is to use the current model date

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!

Comment: Glad it worked. If you found my answer helpful remember to accept it.